# Plotting contour plot along with eigenvector annotations

Tags: plotting

Consider a function

```
F[a_, b_, uaa_, ubb_, uab_, na_, nb_] := 
 a/na*Log[a] + b/nb*Log[b] + (1 - a - b)*Log[1 - a - b] - 
  1/2*uaa*a^2 - 1/2*ubb*b^2 - uab*b*a
```

and its Hessian matrix

```
Hess[a_, b_, uaa_, ubb_, uab_, na_, nb_] := 
 D[F[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, na, nb], {{a, b}, 2}] // Evaluate
```

and the corresponding determinant

```
det[a_, b_, uaa_, ubb_, uab_, na_, nb_] := 
 Det[D[F[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, na, nb], {{a, b}, 2}]] // Evaluate
```

One can visualize the contours of the determinant,

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot[{det[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, 10, 8] == 0},
  {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b}, 0 <= a + b <= 1]],
 {uaa, 0, 10}, {uab, 0, 10, 1}, {ubb, 0, 10}]
```

Alongside these, at a few random (or maybe equally spaced points) on the contour, I would like to visualise the eigenvector corresponding the the minimum eigenvalue.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{plot, contourData, sampledPoints}, 
  plot = ContourPlot[
    det[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, 10, 8] == 0, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}];
  contourData = Cases[Normal[plot], Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity];
  sampledPoints = RandomSample[Flatten[contourData, 1], 10];
  Show[plot, 
   Graphics[{Table[
      With[{vec = 
         Eigensystem[Hess[a, b, uaa, ubb, uab, 10, 8]][[2, 
           2]]}, {Arrowheads[0.02], 
        Arrow[{pt, pt + 0.1 Normalize[vec]}]}], {pt, 
       sampledPoints}]}]]], {uaa, 0, 10}, {uab, 0, 10, 1}, {ubb, 0, 
  10}]
```

The above doesn't work as intended. It gives the error,

```
RandomSample::smplen: RandomSample cannot generate a sample of length 10, which is greater than the length of the sample set {}. If you want a choice of possibly repeated elements from the set, use RandomChoice.
```

Even when the contour data is not empty/should not be empty. Also I am not sure of how to select equally spaced points at all (not super crucial, but a personal preference for visualisation purposes).

Here's a random illustration of what I am going for made in powerpoint (not mathematically correct).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Potentially can be done with (although I am not 100% certain).

```
Module[{plot, contourData, sampledPoints}, 
 plot = ContourPlot[
   det[a, b, 2, 2, 4, 100, 100] == 0, {a, 0.0001, 1}, {b, 0.0001, 1}, 
   PlotPoints -> 25];
 contourData = Cases[Normal[plot], Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity];
 sampledPoints = RandomSample[Flatten[contourData, 1], 10];
 Show[plot, 
  Graphics[{Table[
     With[{vec = 
        Eigensystem[
          Hess[a, b, 2, 1, 5, 100, 100] /. {a -> pt[[1]], 
            b -> pt[[2]]}][[2, 2]]}, {Arrowheads[0.02], 
       Arrow[{pt, pt + 0.1 Normalize[vec]}]}], {pt, 
      sampledPoints}]}]]]
```